# GCBV Generic Class Based View, Django Classes Issue

Tags: django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

$ Hello, I was trying to use "GCBV Generic Class Based View" for edit a post, but it seems not working and event it django can't find my HTML and I don't know why , Hope I get some support ….

$ edit button link

```
{% if post.created_by == user %}
  <div class="mt-3">
  <a class="btn btn-success float-end" 
   href="{% url 'edit_post' post.topic.board.pk post.topic.pk post.pk %}">Edit</a>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

$ edit HTML Page

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %} 
{% block title %}Edit Post{% endblock %}<!-- | Page-title-->
{% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/boards.css' %}">
<div class="newtopic">
  <div class="container container-newtopic w-50">
    <h1>Edit Post</h1>
    <br>
    {% include 'parts/alerts.html' %}
    <div aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb n1-head">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'boards' %}">Boards</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'topics' post.topic.board.pk 
             %}">
                {{post.topic.board.name}}</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page"><a href="">Edit 
              Post</a></li>
        </ol>
       </div>
       <form method="POST" action="" novalidate class="mb-4">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% include 'includes/form.html' %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn main-btn w-100 rounded-pill mt-5">
            Save Changes
        </button>
       </form>
    </div>
  </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

$ Views.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
model = Post
fields = ('message',)
template_name = 'edit_post.html'
pk_url_kwarg = 'post_id'
context_object_name = 'post'
def form_valid(self, form):
    post = form.save(commit=False)
    post.updated_by = self.request.user
    post.updated_date = timezone.now()
    post.save()
    return redirect('topic_posts', board_id=post.topic.board.pk, topic_id=post.topic.pk)
```

$ Urls.py

```
 urlpatterns = [
 path('<int:board_id>/topics/<int:topic_id>/posts/<int:post_id>/edit', 
 views.PostUpdateView.as_view(), name="edit_post"),
 ]
```

$error message

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /boards/4/topics/24/posts/28/edit
  edit_post.html
  Request Method:   GET
  Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/boards/4/topics/24/posts/28/edit
  Django Version:   4.0.5
  Exception Type:   TemplateDoesNotExist
  Exception Value:  edit_post.html
```

Comment: In your view you set the template just as > template = 'edit_post.html'. You should tell your view where exactly is this template. What is the name of your app? Let's assume it's called 'posts'. So you should write in your view: template = 'posts/edit_post.html'.

Comment: And I suggest you store your templates like this: your_app_directory/templates/the_directory_with_the_app_name. Like posts/templates/posts